# How can I make lxml's parser preserve whitespace outside of the root element?

Tags: python, xml, whitespace, lxml

I am using lxml to manipulate some existing XML documents, and I want to introduce as little diff noise as possible. Unfortunately by default [lxml.etree.XMLParser](http://codespeak.net/lxml/api/lxml.etree.XMLParser-class.html) doesn't preserve whitespace before or after the root element of a document:

```
>>> xml = '\n    <etaoin>shrdlu</etaoin>\n'
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(lxml.etree.fromstring(xml))
'<etaoin>shrdlu</etaoin>'
>>> lxml.etree.tostring(lxml.etree.fromstring(xml)) == xml
False
```

Is this possible using lxml? Is it supported by the underlying libxml2?

Comment: according to the lxml docs there should be a `remove_blank_text` option when creating a parser but when I set it to False and test with your xml, it does not seem to work as intended

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Capture the whitespace with a regex and add it back to the string when you're done.

Comment: I stumbled over this answer while searching for a solution to the same problem. But I don't get it; how would you actually accomplish this? What, for example, if a change introduces new attributes or adds a string with whitespace in it? How would you restore whitespace?

Comment: This answer doesn't handle those cases. If you modify the DOM structure the meaning of "preserve whitespace" becomes muddy. To handle structural changes you'd really want to rebuild the whitespace, not restore it.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any XML library that will do it for you. But using a regex sounds like a decent idea if you really need to do this.

```
>>> xml = '\n    <etaoin>shrdlu</etaoin>\n'
>>> head, tail = re.findall(r"^\s*|\s*$", xml)[:2]
>>> root = etree.fromstring(xml)
>>> out = head + etree.tostring(root) + tail
>>> out == xml
True
```